# Assigning raster values to LiDAR point cloud in R?

Tags: raster, r, point, lidar, extract

I am trying to extract several point values for a set of liDAR data. I am starting with the DEM before I jump into the other more complicated values in my raster stack.

Here is my code:

```
library (rLiDAR)    
las<-readLAS("BelottaWallaSC1.las")    
head(las,10)    
library(raster)    
las<-data.frame(las)    
rasValue=extract(rasterdem,las, na.rm=TRUE)    
head(rasValue,10)
```

Here are my errors:

```
> rasValue=extract(rasterdem,las, na.rm=TRUE)
Error in .xyValues(x, as.matrix(y), ...) : xy should have 2 columns only.
Found these dimensions: 56159254, 5
> head(rasvalue,10)
Error in head(rasvalue, 10) : object 'rasvalue' not found
```

Comment: Please try the rlas package:  https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rlas  rLiDAR only contains very old code that supports older LAS files and only some variants.

Comment: What does that `head(las, 10)` show you, and what does it show after `las=data.frame(las)`? How many columns? To extract values from the dem you need a two-column matrix or data frame, which is what the error message is telling you. It looks like it has 5. Pick out the X and Y columns and it might work...

Answer (score 3):

I guess your are trying to get the elevation of the DEM for each point. You can do it from scratch or you can use `lidR`.

From scratch:

```
library(rlas)
library(raster)
las <- read.las("pointcloud.las", select = "xyz")
dem <- raster("dem.tif")
rasValue <- extract(dem, las[,1:2])
```

Using `lidR`

```
library(lidR)
las <- readLAS("pointcloud.las", select = "xyz")
dem <- raster("dem.tif")
las <- merge_spatial(las, dem, "zdem")
rasValue <- las$zdem
```